# Java Spring with swagger2 not starting server

Tags: java, spring

**Hi**,

I'm trying to create a **Java Spring** web application for university classes. I created the **Rest controller** class connected to two service classes. The services classes are connected to the database via **JPA**. When I got rid of the errors related to the build problem, I decided to check if everything is correctly visible in swagger. And here the problem arises because despite creating the configuration file the server does not start. The application compiles correctly but the tomcat server does not appear and it is not possible to connect to the server via **localhost: 8080**. If there were any error, I would manage, but in the console everything looks fine, or I just think so.

### Rest Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class JDBCController {
    @Autowired
    private IDelegationService delegationService;
    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void registerUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {

        userService.save(user);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/changePassword", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void changePassword(@RequestParam("userId") long userId, @RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword) {
        userService.updatePassword(userId, newPassword);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUserById", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean deleteUserById(@RequestParam("userId") long userId) {

        return userService.deleteById(userId);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsersByRoleName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getAllUsersByRoleName(@RequestParam("roleName") String roleName) {
        return userService.getAllUsersByRoleName(roleName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addDelegation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void addDelegation(@RequestParam("userId") long userId, @ModelAttribute Delegation delegation) {

        delegationService.save(userId, delegation);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/removeDelegation", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean removeDelegation(@RequestParam("userId") long userId,
            @RequestParam("delegationId") long delegationId) {
        if (delegationId != 0L) {
            return delegationService.deleteById(delegationId);
        } else if (userId != 0L) {
            return delegationService.deleteByUser(userId);
        }
        return false;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/changeDelegation", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void changeDelegation(@RequestParam("delegationId") long delegationId,
            @ModelAttribute Delegation delegation) {
        delegationService.updateDelegation(delegationId, delegation);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDelegations", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Delegation> getAllDelegations(){
        return delegationService.findAll();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDelegationsOrderByDateStartDesc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Delegation> getAllDelegationsOrderByDateStartDesc(){
        return delegationService.findAllOrderByDateStartDesc();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDelegationsByUserOrderByDateStartDesc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Delegation> getAllDelegationsByUserOrderByDateStartDesc(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId){
        return delegationService.findByUserOrderByDateStartDesc(userId);

    }

}
```

### Swagger config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

     @Bean
      public Docket mainConfig() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/swagger")
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class);
      }
}
```

### pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Laboratorium1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Laboratorium1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.project:Laboratorium1 >----------------------
[INFO] Building Laboratorium1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ Laboratorium1 >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ Laboratorium1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ Laboratorium1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ Laboratorium1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\PSS_Kulesza_Durol\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Laboratorium1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ Laboratorium1 <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ Laboratorium1 ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-16 20:18:07.785  INFO 4176 --- [           main] c.p.L.Laboratorium1Application           : Starting Laboratorium1Application on DESKTOP-7SPKPTP with PID 4176 (C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\PSS_Kulesza_Durol\target\classes started by Admin in C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\PSS_Kulesza_Durol)
2020-03-16 20:18:07.788  INFO 4176 --- [           main] c.p.L.Laboratorium1Application           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-16 20:18:08.357  INFO 4176 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-16 20:18:08.456  INFO 4176 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-16 20:18:08.898  INFO 4176 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-16 20:18:09.040  INFO 4176 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-16 20:18:09.187  INFO 4176 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-16 20:18:09.521  INFO 4176 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-16 20:18:10.116  INFO 4176 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-16 20:18:10.137  INFO 4176 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-03-16 20:18:11.044  INFO 4176 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-16 20:18:11.051  INFO 4176 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-16 20:18:11.720  INFO 4176 --- [           main] c.p.L.Laboratorium1Application           : Started Laboratorium1Application in 4.355 seconds (JVM running for 4.983)
2020-03-16 20:18:11.726  INFO 4176 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-16 20:18:11.729  INFO 4176 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-16 20:18:11.734  INFO 4176 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.320 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-16T20:18:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Thank you in advance for your help.**\

### EDIT.1

## This is how my main method and class look like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Laboratorium1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Laboratorium1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now, as if thinking about it, something should probably be added here so that the configuration file can be seen.

### My project folder:

[image]

Only now I noticed that there is no html file. Looking at the examples, I thought that it would generate itself but apparently I was wrong. Someone knows where I can download it from.

Comment: Can you show your main method and class containing it?

Comment: 1. replace `spring-web`(pom-dependency) with the according "spring-**boot**-starter-web" (or configure "web" manually) 2. ensure `JDBCController` is "picked up" (sub-package of spring-application, or custom..)  The log confirms your observation: no server startet at no port.

Comment: Based on the attached log, it seems that the application did not start, but only was built.

Comment: @xerx593 I just added this dependency. Could you tell how to make sure that the configuration class is seen by spring?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas In the first edit I added the main method and its class.

Comment: by default, spring scans the package (+ sub-packages) of the `@SpringBootApplication`, you can fine tune/re-configure with [`@ComponentScan`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html)

Comment: (looking at the file structure: your jdbc controller is ok/visible/applies to default config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **one additional dependency** in your pom.xml file for Spring Boot's (embedded Tomcat) server to start: **spring-boot-starter-web** Add that and you will be good to go.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I added it and the server started to work but the swagger still doesn't.